# gcc : permission denied after new installion

Tags: gcc, installation

It's a new installation on **Deepin OS**. I wanted to install **gcc-8.3.0** on my computer.

I've done this manually cause it only propose me gcc-6 with apt. So I've installed all the depedency (GMP, MPFR, MPC, isl...) then I've proceeded to gcc. I've followed this tutorial : https://archerfmy.github.io/2017/04/12/How-to-switch-your-gcc-g-version-in-ubuntu/ to add the new installation. But now the problem is that I can't use gcc anymore.

---

```
gcc 
zsh: permission denied: gcc
```

---

```
which -a gcc
gcc not found
```

Comment: Not very familiar with Deepin OS, but can't you use the Ubuntu toolchain PPA to install the latest GCC though apt?

Comment: I've already tried this sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test but it's result in : 
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Deepin/stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found ! It's seem pretty obvious now but while reading `update-alternatives`'s man page I have realized that I wasn't putting the right parameters. In fact, I was giving the path to the directory of gcc-8.3.0 but not the path to gcc himself. I mean, only `/usr/lib/gcc-8.3.0` instead of `/usr/lib/gcc-8.3.0/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0`. It had take me so long to find out, f me.

In my case the right cmd was :

---

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/lib/gcc-8.3.0/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0 50
```

Hope it can help someone else and saving him time.